# How can Draupadi be a pathivrata (dutiful wife) while being married to 5 men?

Tags: mahabharata, dharma, women, draupadi

What are the qualities and requirements needed to be a *[pathivrata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sati_(practice)#Pativrata)*?

Draupadi is considered to be one of the [Panchkannyas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchakanya), and a great pathivrata too. [This link](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/231/why-did-all-the-pandavas-marry-draupadi/%22link%22) says why Draupadi married 5 persons (the Pandavas). Is that sacred or pure? Does it have any effect on the pathivrata state?

If there's nothing wrong, according to Hindu scripture (forget current law), can a Hindu woman marry more than one person at a time?

My question is, briefly explain the Hinduism and Veda perspective on polyandry.

Can a woman achieve pathivrata state even though she marries more than one person at a time?

(P.S. My main question is about the Veda perspective on polyandry; my other questions and statements were made in support of the main question. Please answer this considering Draupadi as an example and the Hindu woman in real time)

Comment: 1. There is no evidence of Vedas supporting polyandry. 2. Draupadi is only a seeming exception. Draupadi in her previous birth was swarga lakshmi and all the 5 pandavas were Indra re-born. So one can say she is a pativrata.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Not all Pandavas were rebirth/Incarnation of Indra, only arjuna was incarnation of Indra and Nara.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandava#Parents_of_the_Pandavas

Comment: @Yogi No Yogi. There is another story about the previous life of Draupadi and the Pandavas all being amsa's of Indra.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Oh Okay Thanks following link made it clear http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6682/who-were-the-previous-indras-that-incarnated-as-the-pandavas

Answer (score 7):

I have heard in upanyasams (discourses in Tamil by Krishna premi anna) that Draupadi is a combination of 5 shaktis (pancha-shakti-mayi devi) of the 5 devas of whom pandavas are amshas (or sons). Her arrangement was of living 1 year alone with each pandava, while none of the others would enter their premises. She would do 'agni-pravesh' (entering fire) and take on new body after each year of stay before starting to live with another pandava, thus getting purified by fire.
The story of Arjuna breaking the arrangement while she was in Yudhishtira's quarters in order to help a poor brahmana, and going on pilgrimage to atone for it, is well-known.

Answer (score 6):

Every women has many husbands because after death, we will get new body and new husband that is not a sin only in one birth u should have only one husband this is what  shastras said. but Draupadi changes her body gaining new virgin body for each pandava and always faithful to each pandava at that time not with relation with other pandava with heart and body so draupadi changes her body. It means she gains new birth that is not a sin so she always had purity with body and heart not with soul. Soul can change many husbands

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE! Place.cite some sources from authentic Hindu Scriptures like Mahabharata etc.in your answer.Answers on this site should be provided with citing of appropriate sources.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Draupadi is a pathivrata.

Because as per **Markandeya Purana**:

> The adorable Indra became incarnate in five forms (5 Pandavas). His wife was born as Draupadi from Agni: she is the wife of Indra alone, and of no one else.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

---

Related Question(s):

[Is Draupadi a goddess?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10156/is-draupadi-a-goddess)

[Why did all the Pandavas marry Draupadi?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/231/why-did-all-the-pandavas-marry-draupadi)

Comment: I think this Puranic story was invented later to counter the backlash in the then society on the idea of woman being simultaneously married to 5 men. "The adorable Indra became incarnate in five forms (5 Pandavas)" - not true. Only Arjuna was born of Indra's seed. Not the other 4 Pandavas.

Comment: @sv. Pls see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23974 this is mentioned in Adi Parva->Vaivahika Parva of Mahabharata too..

Comment: Ok, saw that, but it doesn't say anything about the 4 other Pandavas born of Indra. Compare your quotes to the birth stories of all 5 Pandavas. Do they tally? If they don't, we have a problem of interpolation or retelling of original events (with new stories/explanations added to satisfy the doubting people).

Comment: @sv. It matches if we read complete Mahabharata.. :)