# Do we have any information about previous births of Yudishthir, Bheem, Nakul and Sehdev?

Tags: mahabharata, karma, pandavas

In Mahabharata, we see that Pandava brothers have suffered a lot. Even when they were suppose to rule, they had to spend their large part of life in forests or fighting their own cousins or family members or watching their sons getting killed. I wonder why they had to suffer this much. Do they have any previous births and they were redeeming for the bad karmas of their previous birth. Till now I only know of only Arjuna's previous birth, ie, Sage Nara from Nara-Narayan duo. But in that life too, I don't think he has done any evil. Do we have any reference to previous births of other Pandava brothers.

Comment: I discuss the Pandavas' previous births in my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6682/36

Comment: @Keshav, Thanks for reminding me of this question. I don't know how I forgot this one. I saw that even I commented on your question. But somehow I am not able to get convinced with this story as Indras just got punishment for not recognizing Lord Shiva. I mean if they had done any bad against others or mis performed their duties then it is understood but just not recognizing doesnot create a big ground for such punishment.

Comment: Well, the problem wasn't just not recognizing Shiva, the problem is that they were far too arrogant, and they didn't realize that there were beings above themselves.  In any case, should I close your question as a duplicate?

Comment: @Keshav Yes please..as your question has answered my question, so its ok to be marked as duplicate.