# Goddess Shree and the five Indras

Tags: pandavas, indra

> Draupadi was also an avatar of Goddess Shree or Wealth who was the wife to five Indras in their mortal manifestation, that is, the five Pandavas. She was born many times for **imprisoning** the Indras. Her first birth was as Vedavati (the avatar of Swaha, Agni's wife) who cursed Ravana. She then came again as Maya-Sita, especially to take revenge from Ravana, while Agni hid the real Sita. The third birth was partial - she was both Damayanti and her daughter Nalayani. She married Sage Mudgala. Her fifth avatar was that of Draupadi herself.

How did Shree marry the five Indras in her other avatars?Also, why did she imprison her **own husbands**?

On a separate note, please explain why and how sometimes **sons** are considered as **avatars** of certain gods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who were the previous Indras that incarnated as the Pandavas?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6682/who-were-the-previous-indras-that-incarnated-as-the-pandavas)

Comment: i am not asking **who** the Pandavas are,

Comment: One of the questions within the [other question](http://goo.gl/TzBWoX) is _But what were their life stories and when did they live?_ An answer to that would certainly cover what you are asking here from Draupadi's perspective (which is why I marked this as a possible duplicate). BTW, you should probably move the last question (_sons being avatars of gods_ into a separate question). Also, it seems you are quoting something in the 1st paragraph, so you could use [blockquotes](http://goo.gl/RIO99e) for that and also provide a link to the source of the text you referenced.

Comment: @sv I was not able to find the answer to my questions , **how** and **why** did the goddess Shree marry and imprison her own husbands.If anybody knows the answer,please tell me

Comment: Does **anybody** know the answers to my questions?!?!?!?

Comment: You can ping [Keshav](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/36/keshav-srinivasan) in [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) using "@KeshavSrinivasan" and see if he has any clues.