# How many Indras did Shiva imprison?

Tags: shiva, pandavas, indra

After reading [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6682/who-were-the-previous-indras-that-incarnated-as-the-pandavas), I decided to do some research.
However,there were two contradicting ideas: some said that Shiva had **4** Indras trapped in the cave while others said that there were **5** Indras.Note that these Indras were there before the present Indra came.

How many Indras did Shiva really imprison?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Adi Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01200.htm) of Mahabharata Lord Shiva had imprisoned four Indras in the cave of mountain.

> The illustrious Isana of fierce energy then said unto him, 'Act not, O Sakra, ever again in this way.Remove this huge stone, for thy strength and energy are immeasurable, and enter the hole (it will disclose) where await some others possessing the splendour of the sun and who are all like unto thee.' Indra, then, on removing that stone, beheld a cave in the breast of that king of mountains, **within which were four others resembling himself**.

So the conclusion is that Lord Shiva had Imprisoned four Indras in the cave and further the fifth Indra ( that was the Indra of that time ) get imprisoned by him.

Comment: according tpo the link above,there wre 4 Indras before the present indra came along

Comment: Yeah that's what i mean

Comment: sorry i meant five

Comment: The number actually depends on how you are counting. If you include present Indra they were five but before present Indra get imprisoned they were four. I hope you got it.

Comment: okay i get it but the link specifically says

Comment: >To punish Indra for his arrogance, Shiva forced Indra into an underground cave, which contained other five people. It turns out that Shiva had given the same test to five previous Indras as well, and he imprisoned them because they failed it. But Shiva offered the Indras a way to redemption:

Comment: In the question you are referring whatever you just quoted is not from sources. I mean the chapter of Mahabharata he is referring itself says that there were four Indras before present Indra. Possibly [@Keshav Shrinivasan](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/36/keshav-srinivasan) mistakenly mentioned it as five as It is not found in his referred link.