# Clarification on Arjun's statement on Bhima's marriage?

Tags: mahabharata, marriage

As per [Mahabharata: Adi Parva: Swayamvara Parva: Section CLXLIII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01194.htm), the intelligent king (Yudhishthira) told Dhananjaya,

> 'By thee, O Phalguna, hath Yajnaseni been won. It is proper, therefore, that thou shouldst wed her. O thou withstander of all foes, igniting the sacred fire, take thou her hand with due rites.'

Arjuna, hearing this, replied,

> O king, do not make me a participator in sin. Thy behest is not conformable to virtue. That is the path followed by the sinful. Thou shouldst wed first, then the strong-armed Bhima of inconceivable feats, then myself,...

But, Bhima was already married to Hidimva by that time. So what does that mean?

And why this point was not raised when Bhima got married to Hidimva that he should not get married before Yudhisthira?

---

Later, Yudhishthir also says similar things

> I am unmarried still, and Bhima also is so amongst the sons of Pandu. ~ [Did Kunti explicitly told Pandavas to marry Draupadi?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/did-kunti-explicitly-told-pandavas-to-marry-draupadi)

Comment: What clarification do u want? It is well known that as per scriptures the younger brother should not marry before his elder brothers.

Comment: @Rickross yes, I know that rule...1. but Bhima was already married by that time, so Arjun can marry right? 2. How Bhima got married to Hidimva before Yudhishthir's marriage as it's against rule (youngers can marry only when elder brother is unfit for marriage)?

Comment: 1. May be they did not consider it as a proper marriage as Hidimba was a Rakshasi. 2. Again the same (marriage not counted as a proper one) or may be Bhima did not care to follow the rule. Even gods sometimes fail to follow rules so what's the big deal that Bhima also didn't. He was after all a human being.

Comment: @Rickross so u mean they didn't consider that proper marriage..but still it must hv been of some type out of 8 marriages...so how unmarried???And any scripture which says that Rakshasi/Gandharva/Asura (or whatever category u put that) Vivah can be done before elder brother's marriage?

Comment: Rakshasa Vivaha (or any kinds of Vivaha) is done between humans only (or between same kinds of beings) but here it's weird one candidate is a human being whereas the other is a Rakshas. So I don't know what kind of marriage was that and if that was a valid marriage from the perspective of Dharma or not.

Comment: When Bhima married Hidimba, it was approved by Yudhistira. I think the rule is younger brother must have elder brother's approval if he wishes to marry first (if not done, he should give his wife to elder brother first).

Comment: Arjuna participated in the svayaṁvara as the representative of Yudhiṣṭhira, not for having vivāha with Draupadī himself. But the case of Hiḍimbā is special, she fell in love with Bhīma only and chose to have vivāha with him, and Kuntī and Yudhiṣṭhira approved of it.