# Did Draupdi marry only Yudhistira?

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavata-purana

Today I watched [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scbxuxmJ5hI)

As per this video, I am confused due to the opinions and thoughts stated by the youtuber. He says that Draupdi married only Yudhistira and not all five Pandavas. He also says, in the Mahabharata epic it is not written that Draupdi married all Pandavas.

I also find the act of Draupdi marrying the five brothers to be bizzare since polyandry is considered as sin.

Comment: This is opinion based question.Delete this post ASAP

Comment: No, she married all the Pandavas and there is no doubt in it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can Draupadi be a pathivrata (dutiful wife) while being married to 5 men?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/4043/how-can-draupadi-be-a-pathivrata-dutiful-wife-while-being-married-to-5-men) and [Why did all the Pandavas marry Draupadi?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/231/why-did-all-the-pandavas-marry-draupadi/23974)

Comment: https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01201.htm : She married to Yushisthira first but after that with other pandavas too.. "Then those mighty car-warriors,--those perpetuators of the Kuru line,--those princes attired in gorgeous dresses, took the hand of that best of women, day by day in succession, aided by that priest"... Markandeya purana justifies this "The adorable Indra became incarnate in five forms (5 Pandavas). His wife was born as Draupadi from Agni: she is the wife of Indra alone, and of no one else."